# command line tool to list socket options that are currently set

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, winsock2

Is there a command line tool in windows that lists all the socket options that are currently set on a tcp socket? I am looking for something that lists all tcp connections in a process, and for each connection shows me the socket options that are set.

I have one client application that has zero latency (when talking to a service), and another that has a 45ms latency - so I thought a comparison of the socket options set on the two applications might help me figure out what is wrong.

I am using resource monitor to see the latency for the tcp connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the list of TCP connections that belong to a given process is easy.  [`GetTcpTable2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx), [`GetTcp6Table2()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408405.aspx), and [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) all report owning process IDs for open TCP connections.

Getting the options that are set for a given process's open sockets, on the other hand, is not trivial.

There is no API that specifically returns a list of socket handles for a given process, so you have to manually enumerate kernel handles looking for open sockets for the desired process:

[C++ Get Handle of Open Sockets of a Program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330379/65863)

[socket handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/socket-handles_topic1193.html)

Then you have to inject your own code into that process, such as with [`CreateRemoteThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx), and have the code either:

1. duplicate the socket handles via [`WSADuplicateSocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565.aspx) and pass them to your app so it can use [`WSASocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212.aspx) to access them, such as to call [`getsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738544.aspx) on them.
2. query the sockets directly for the desired info, and then pass that back to your app.

Either way, there is no API to retrieve a given socket's list of current options.  You have to query every individual option one at a time.