# On modern Windows NT systems only, can I determine at runtime whether a handle refers to a socket or an object handle?

Tags: windows, sockets, winapi, winsock

I am fully aware that in the past Windows sockets used to be implemented as third party user mode DLLs only and that sockets and object handles were unrelated. However, on modern Windows NT systems sockets are full kernel objects although there is some user mode state as well.

Comment: How did you end up finding a handle whose provenance you don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no single API for that particular query.  You have to access the NT Object Manager directly and locate the desired handle within its list of known handles, then you can retrieve the handle's object type (amongst other things).

[Inside NT's Object Manager](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/inside-nts-object-manager)

[Pushing the Limits of Windows: Handles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx)

[HOWTO: Enumerate handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html)

[WinObj: The ultimate Object Manager namespace viewer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657)

**Update**: I forgot about [NtQueryObject()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383.aspx).  You can query a `HANDLE` for its `ObjectTypeInformation` class, which returns a `PUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION` struct:

```
typedef struct __PUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION {
    UNICODE_STRING TypeName;
    ULONG Reserved [22];    // reserved for internal use
} PUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION, *PPUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION;
```

For example:

```
std::wstring GetHandleTypeName(HANDLE hHandle)
{
    typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *NtQueryObjectPtr)(
          HANDLE Handle,
          OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS ObjectInformationClass,
          PVOID ObjectInformation,
          ULONG ObjectInformationLength,
          PULONG ReturnLength);

    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary(_T("NtDll.dll"));
    NtQueryObjectPtr QueryObj = (NtQueryObjectPtr) ::GetProcAddress(hMod, "NtQueryObject");
    ASSERT(QueryObj);

    ULONG OutSize = 0;
    NTSTATUS NtStatus = QueryObj(hHandle, ObjectTypeInformation, NULL, 0, &OutSize);
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer(OutSize);
    PPUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION TypeInfo = (PPUBLIC_OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION) &buffer[0];
    ULONG InSize = OutSize;
    NtStatus = QueryObj(hHandle, ObjectTypeInformation, TypeInfo, InSize, &OutSize);
    return std::wstring(TypeInfo->TypeName.Buffer, TypeInfo->TypeName.Length);
}
```

```
std::wstring cs = GetHandleTypeName((HANDLE)TheDesiredSocket);
MessageBoxW(cs.c_str());
```

See these for some more information about using `NtQueryObject()` with Sockets:

[C++ Get Handle of Open Sockets of a Program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16330379/65863)

[socket handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/socket-handles_topic1193.html)

Comment: That sounds like it'd be slow as well which would also be bad.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't sockets implemented as *File* handles? The handle type can be queried using the native API, specifically [NtQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556684.aspx) (see [ZwQueryObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567062.aspx) for documentation). Passing `ObjectTypeInformation` as the [OBJECT_INFORMATION_CLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550964.aspx) will get you the object type name.

Comment: @IInspectable: beat me to it..  I was in the process of adding that info to my answer when you posted your comment.

Comment: [This function may be changed or removed from Windows without further notice.] That's a pity.

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus: on the other hand, Microsoft rarely actually does that for most APIs.  Granted, the Nt/Zw functions are internal functions, and more susceptible to change since most apps should not be calling them directly. But devs who do use them need to be aware of their volatility since they are internal functions.

Comment: I don't believe that you are allowed to use these functions for applications certified for Windows Phone though right?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus: I would not know, as I do not do any Windows Phone development.  But I suspect not.