# C++ Release network port that is used by another process on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, port, winsock

**Edit: I can't see anything wrong with my question. It is not a duplicate, even though people have accused it to be. If you decide to down-vote the question anyways, please tell me why, so I can understand.  Thank you.**

How can I force another process to close a port that it is currently using. **For example** if Skype is listening on port 80 locally. How can I  programmatically force Skype to release that port again, so that I can run XAMPP on the same port properly? Without changing Skype settings or closing Skype.

Yes, I know this might lead to unexpected behavior.

Is it just a matter of closing a handle using [DuplicateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566445%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or how is it done?

I'm not interested in closing the process or finding out which process is blocking the port. I already knkw how that's done properly even without netstat.

**Edit**:
I found [WSADuplicateSocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which looked promising. But it has to be called from the process that already has the `Descriptor identifying the local socket` as Microsoft calls it. If I could somehow get that `Descriptor identifying the local socket` I might be able to call [closesocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on that. This could probably be done with come code injecting, but I'm sure there is a better way.

**Edit**:
A tool called `CurrPorts` is allegedly able to do what I'm trying to do. So it's definitely possible... but how?

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?  Force close Skype. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788348/how-do-i-free-my-port-80-on-localhost-windows?rq=1

Comment: You can turn off the option "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections" in skype.

Comment: That is not what I asked for. Neither am I interested in force closing any process, nor am I looking to change other applications settings. I spare you the answer on "why this is tagged with C++". If you truly think this question deserves a down-vote please tell me why. You surely can't expect me to provide a code of "what I've tried" here..

Comment: You can't seriously expect that a modern operating system is going to provide you with a facility to break other processes.

Comment: Oh, yes I can. You see DuplicateObject already provides functionality to to close other processes handles. And this is definitely not necessarily breaking the process. And even if. Closeing a process could cause just as much damage as this, potentially even more.

Comment: [Forcing handles closed is not a good idea](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx).

Comment: I am well aware of that. Although I would say "not necessarily" instead. I know what you mean though.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way to access a socket from another process is to inject code into that process that calls `WSADuplicateSocket()` to duplicate the desired socket handle for access by your process, then send the details to your process via IPC, and access the socket via `WSASocket()`.  See:

[C++ Get Handle of Open Sockets of a Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262114/)

However, a more brute-force approach would be to use [`DuplicateHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) with the `DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE` flag instead.  No need for code injection:

- Find the process ID that owns the open port you want (see [`GetTcpTable2()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408406.aspx) and [`GetExtendedTcpTable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) and other related functions)
- use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to open a handle to the process ID
- enumerate the process's open handles via [`NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509.aspx) (see [HOWTO: Enumerate handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-enumerate-handles_topic18892.html)), looking for open socket objects.
- use [`NtDeviceIoControlFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648411.aspx) to query each socket handle for its IP/port information to figure out which socket object is using the port you want (see [Socket handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/socket-handles_topic1193.html)).
- then finally `DuplicateHandle()` the found socket handle to close it (no need to specify a target to duplicate it to).

Comment: I enumerated through all the handles and logged what types of handles I got. Here is the full list: http://pastebin.com/DZDTgZ7K I couldn't identify anything as a "socket object". I'm also not sure if sockets really have handles, as Microsoft always talks about `Descriptors` rather than `Handles` when it comes to sockets.

Comment: @Forivin sockets are kernel objects on Windows, and have real handles. See [Socket handles](http://forum.sysinternals.com/socket-handles_topic1193.html) for how to detect them during handle enumeration and query their port details.